# Unknown option `breakable' for package `tcolorbox'?

Tags: errors, tcolorbox

I am running TeXLive 2012 however when I run this...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, title=My breakable box]
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

I get this error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `breakable' for package `tcolorbox'.
```

The package works fine with unbroken boxes. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you need to update your system or at least `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using breakable, you must load the library : breakable.
refer to the doc : texdoc tcolorbox section 9

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks, breakable, skins}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, breakable, title=My breakable box]
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As it stands I don't see how this answers the question and you don't explain that.  Can you please updated.